# Creating an index in my table does not lower my cost

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
accident_info
(
    accident_index varchar(20),
    first_road_class varchar(20),
    accident_severity varchar(20),
    date date,
    urban_or_rural_area varchar(20),
    weather_conditions varchar(40),
    year int,
    inscotland varchar(20)
);
```

And against this table, I execute the following query :

```
select count(accident_index)as hits, first_road_class 
from accident_info 
group by first_road_class;
```

without index.

I would like to create an index to lower my Aggregate Cost but the one I've made so far doesn't seem to work. This is:

```
create index on accident_info(accident_index, first_road_class);
```

[First ten Rows of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGU7r.png)

Comment: Did you check with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` if the index is actually used ?

Comment: i checked and it was not used, thank you for responding so quickly

Comment: Could you add a unique index field using numbers and try indexing that?

Comment: Well, it is a project for uni, and the rows/columns are fixed, so i cannot add another if that is what you mean. thanks a lot

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). But as your query needs to read all rows, it's unlikely an index will help here. Enabling parallel might give you more performance improvement than an index.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it turned out to be that my query needed to read all rows, so an index is a bad idea, i guess he wanted us to find that out and write that down

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select count(accident_index) as hits, first_road_class 
from accident_info 
group by first_road_class;
```

You can try an index on `accident_info(first_road_class, accident_index)`.  The order of the columns is important.

Comment: We tried and it did not work, thank you for your time

Comment: This would help the sgbd to do not fetch the heap table and just scan the index leaf nodes

Comment: This will only help if you get an *index only scan*. You will only get an index only scan if you recently `VACUUM`ed the table.